Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f\in \mathscr D(\Omega).$ Then Prove that following sets $K_1$ and $K_2$ are compact and disjoint.
Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be an open set.
$\mathscr D(\Omega)=\{f|f \in C^\infty(\Omega) \wedge \text{supp}(f)\subseteq \Omega \text{ is compact.}\}$

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f\in \mathscr D(\Omega).$ Then Prove that $K_1=\{ x\in \Omega| f(x)\ge \epsilon\}$ and $K_2= \{ x\in \Omega| f(x)\leq -\epsilon\}$ are compact and disjoint.

My attempt:-
I know the definition of $\text{supp}(f)=\overline{\{ x\in \mathbb R^n: f(x)\neq 0\}}.$
Disjointness of $K_1$ and $K_2$
Let $x\in K_1\cap K_2\implies f(x)\leq -\epsilon \wedge f(x) \ge \epsilon $
No such exists. If exists, It violates the well definition of $f.$
$K_1=f^{-1}([\epsilon, \infty))$ and $K_2=f^{-1}((-\infty, -\epsilon])$ are closed. ($\because f$  is a continuous function.)
I don'tknow how to proceed.
Thank you.

Something seriously wrong. $K_1$ and $K_2$ are obviously not disjoint.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8B188fpwd_U&list=PLOVXtREUtUHPfQRgVNsqkoZmm-QjYNtay&index=4&ab_channel=NPTEL-NOCIITM

@geetha290krm could you check 19:20 of this video by NPTEL? He says like that.

You made  a horrible mistake in the definition of $K_2$.

Sorry for that. I got it.

@geetha290krm I have corrected. Thank you for your correction.

$K_1$ and $K_2$ are subsets of the support of $f$ (which is compact). Closed subsets of compact sets are compact.
